# MongoDB version 2.6.10, or is it?

Tags: mongodb

This is a weird, weird question. I provisioned a Mongo replica set using one of the Rackspace stack templates.

When running `db.version()` in the Mongo shell, it says the version is `2.6.10`.

However, there's a few things I've noticed that indicate that the version is actually in the `2.4` series:

- `db.createUser` is undefined
- Using an `explain` option in `db.collection.aggregate` doesn't do anything

Am I being stupid here? Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Do you use robomongo?

Comment: I'm using the Mongo shell.

Comment: Did you add parameters to db.createUser() ? You might mistake it for undefined if you don't add the user, pwd and roles parameters.

Comment: See here: db.createUser({ user: 'christophe', pwd: 'mysupersecret', roles: [{ role: 'dbOwner', db: 'scales_partitioned' }] })
Tue Jun  2 13:27:55.622 TypeError: Property 'createUser' of object admin is not a function

Comment: Your problem is really weird. Are you on linux? Does typing mongo --version in the terminal also return 2.6? What about mongod --version

Comment: I know right! mongo --version gives MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10. mongod --version gives db version v2.6.10.

Comment: For the record. Though not "officially documented" an "explain" argument to `.aggregate()` works from 2.4.9 and above.`db.serverstatus().version` is also a fair equiv of the commands you have tried. As long as your shell is 2.6 or greater then you should not see those results.

Comment: `db.serverStatus().version` gives back v2.6.10 as well, I guess a re-install of MongoDB is on the cards...

Comment: What does `version()` report in the `mongo` shell? That's the shell version which has the helpers you are suggesting aren't working (vs checking the server with `db.version()`). Are you using any shell helpers like `mongo-hacker`? You could try starting the shell with `mongo --norc` to be sure.

Comment: `version()` is reporting 2.6.10, same with `mongo --norc` as well. Not using any helpers to my knowledge.